# Datepicker for MVC View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.net mvc razor and I need to implament datepicker in some fields.
Maybe someone could offer a useful nuget package to do so in MVC razor view?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this one :

> Install-Package jQuery.UI.Widgets.Datepicker

Comment: if that helps accept it as an answer, may help others in future.

Comment: Just wanted to try it. Datepicker works great:)

Comment: glad to know it worked for you.